# Automating a MSACCESS application with powershell

Tags: ms-access, powershell, automation, sendkeys

I want to be able to use the Sendwait function to automate a MS-ACCESS application using powershell commands. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get a handle in the usual way to the actual application window. I can get a handle to MS-ACCESS itself, but attempts using Sendwait to automate the window failed.

Comment: [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("MSACCESS")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("123456") doesn't work because I don't have the handle to the actual application window.

Answer (score 7):

Any reason why you need to send keys? Why not just use the methods and properties of the object in question.

Just go:

To launch Access, open a database, and then print a report, and then quit?

```
$Acc = New-Object –com Access.Application

$Acc.OpenCurrentDataBase("c:\t.accdb")
$Acc.docmd.OpenReport("rptCustomers")
$Acc.Quit()
```

So most if not all methods and properties of the Access application can be used via power-shell, and as a result, I don't think you need nor want to attempt using some type of send keys as that tends to be rather flakey and a poor way to automate things. You might want to point out what commands or what you require, but you can also call VBA code this way, and as noted, even add records etc.